# CSS: UL Navigation - on hover, background color error

Tags: css, html-lists, navigationbar

On hover the background color seems to come outside of the "boxes" that are my navigation items. I have tried tweaking everything. Here is my CSS and HTML...

```
<div id="menuTop">

 <ul id="menuOne" class="menuHoriz">
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="communication.html">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="help.html">samples</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

#menuTop {
clear: both;
padding-top: 18px;
height: 55px;
font-size: 12pt;
background-color: #000;
 }

#menuTop ul, #menuTop li {
margin: 0;
padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

#menuTop ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

#menuTop li {
display: block;
background-color: #3C87D1;
text-align: center;
width: 197px;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 0px 0 0;
padding: 4px 0 0 0;
border: 1px solid #2A5E92;
}

#menuTop a {
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

#menuTop a:link, #menuTop a:visited {
width: 197px;
height: 30px;
padding: 4px 0 0 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menuTop a:hover {
width: 197px;
height: 30px;
padding: 4px 0 0 0;
margin: 0;
color: #fff;
background-color: #5F9FFF;
}

ul.menuHoriz li {
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the unneeded/double definitions from your stylesheet and fixed the bug.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#menuTop {
    font: 12pt 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 18px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #000
}
#menuTop ul {
    padding-top: 4px;
    list-style: none
}
#menuTop li {
    background: #3C87D1;
    border: 1px solid #2A5E92;
    text-align: center
}
#menuTop a {
    display: block;
    width: 197px;
    line-height: 30px
}
#menuTop a:link, #menuTop a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none
}
#menuTop a:hover {
    background-color: #5F9FFF
}
ul.menuHoriz li {
    float: left
}
```

Here are some notes:

- It is handy to set the margin and padding for all elements to zero by using `*`, before designing your layout.
- Set the width and height for your menu item to the `a` element only (the most nested element). The surrounding `li` element will take the same size. Also use `line-height` instead of `height` because it automatically makes your text vertically centered.
- Don't redefine styles in `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover` or `:active` (for example dimensions and font). It gives unnecessary calculations for the browser.

Comment: Midas can you tell me how I would add push the container down from the top now? It is now pushed against the top, I tried adding padding to the container to move it down about 10px or so and it just ended up separating my header from my border.

Comment: What do you mean 'separating my header from my border'?

Comment: The border appears pushed to the top. When I try to add padding to the top of the container, the border still appears pushed to the top, but my header is pushed down, leaving room where you can see the body background image. Basically all padding is not seeming to be in place anymore and I don't know how to fix that-any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I got it-I added the "0" padding elements to menutop and menutop ul and removed the 0's from the top of the CSS. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only the color coming outside the boxes, add this to your **#menuTop li**

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Works for me.  :)

Comment: This is far easier than what I proposed. Here's a demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/LN26d/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/fxx6Y/3/)

```
#menuTop {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 18px;
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 34px;    
}
#menuTop a {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #2A5E92;
    background-color: #3C87D1;
    width: 197px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menuTop a:hover {
    background-color: #5F9FFF;
}
```